# ARP Retry count exceeded in uboot

Tags: linux, networking, embedded-linux, ping, u-boot

I was testing my Ethernet connection on my i.MX6 Board in u-boot

I used the following commands:

```
setenv ipaddr xx.xx.xx.xx
setenv serverip xx.xx.xx.xx
setenv netmask xx.xx.xx.xx
setenv gatewayip xx.xx.xx.xx
setenv ethaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

When I do a ping to my address it fails

```
=> ping xx.xx.xx.xx
Using FEC device

ARP Retry count exceeded; starting again

ARP Retry count exceeded; starting again

=> mii info
PHY 0x00: OUI = 0x209A, Model = 0x01, Rev = 0x00, 100baseT, FDX

=> mii dump 0 0
0.     (3100)                 -- PHY control register --
  (8000:0000) 0.15    =     0    reset
  (4000:0000) 0.14    =     0    loopback
  (2040:2000) 0. 6,13 =   b01    speed selection = 100 Mbps
  (1000:1000) 0.12    =     1    A/N enable
  (0800:0000) 0.11    =     0    power-down
  (0400:0000) 0.10    =     0    isolate
  (0200:0000) 0. 9    =     0    restart A/N
  (0100:0100) 0. 8    =     1    duplex = full
  (0080:0000) 0. 7    =     0    collision test enable
  (003f:0000) 0. 5- 0 =     0    (reserved)
```

What can be the error. I have seen in NXP Website, that fake MAC Address will not work with ping.. How to make it work..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we need to check whether the MAC address is properly written into H/W register, i.e. basically `SpecAdd1top` and `SpecAdd1bottom` registers (which holds the MAC address). Read the value of these 2 registers and whether they are perfectly matching with assigned MAC address or not.

- Need to verify whether ARP request is reaching on server PC by running Wireshark on server side PC. If it is reaching, then it's not getting ARP response to target board within its ARP timeout timing is 5 ms. It seems like ARP request is not reaching to the server side, which means it is not sending ARP request properly.
- Check the ENET MAC successfully sending ARP request or not from the u-boot ethernet MAC driver.
- Increase the ARP timeout time from 5ms to some more ms.

Answer (score 0):

Use wireshark or tcpdump to validate what is actually happening on the "wire". As modern ethernet is switched you need to find a way to actually see that particular ethernet segment. This is easy if your device is connected via a cross over cable and you have your laptop on the other side. Otherwise you might have to configure your switch so it copies traffic from a certain port to the port where your laptop is attached.

Comment: The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to setup the network adapter using the *dhcp* command instead of using *setenv*.

Using *dhcp* you verify that you have a working network connection and you can display the correct values for the environment variables that you are currently setting manually using *printenv*.

> If a basic ping doesn't work with a static IP address, what makes you think a DHCP request has a better chance of success?

Static addresses can be set up incorrectly. E.g. if the wrong gateway or network mask is specified you may not be able to ping a target.

Comment: If a basic `ping` doesn't work with a static IP address, what makes you think a DHCP request has a better chance of success?